# How do I delete a range (hash) in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails Console

> q=Article.last(3) 
>  
>   q.delete

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

> q.destroy

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for #<Array:0x0000000901b6d0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`destroy_all`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all)

```
q = Article.order(id: :desc).limit(3)
q.destroy_all
```

or With your approach

```
q = Article.last(3) 
q.map(&:destroy)
# or
Article.where(id: q.map(&:id)).destroy_all
```

You can also chain `destroy_all` to `where`

```
Article.where(some_condition).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Article.destroy_all(id: q.map(&:id))
```

OR

```
Article.destroy q.map{ |a| a.id }
```